# Does the Ruby rescue statement work with require?

Tags: ruby, require, modifier, rescue

Does the Ruby **`rescue`** statement modifier work with **`require`**?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'a' rescue nil
LoadError: no such file to load -- a
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rescue from a `LoadError` you just need to use the `begin/end` style and not use the inline `rescue`:

This works as you expect:

```
begin
 require 'a'
rescue LoadError => ex
 puts "Load error: #{ex.message}"
end
```

Comment: @RamondeCValle the `rescue` statement modifier only rescues [`StandardError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/StandardError.html) (and its subclasses). [`LoadError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/LoadError.html) isn’t a subclass of `StandardError`.